# How to establish a connection between PLC and MongoDB (NoSQL) using Structured Text programming?

Tags: mongodb, sockets, tcp, plc, structured-text

How do I send data (a character, an integer or a string, for example) from a PLC (Indraworks) to MongoDB using Structured Text programming (IEC 61131-3)?

None of the function blocks available (RIL_SocketComm.library) are compatible with NoSQL databases (MongoDB in this case). Is there a workaround?

It would be great if you could help me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually that depends upon which plc you have and what function it supports most plcs with Ethernet support can do this. all you have do is enble this feature. For example Schneider LMC058 and LMC258 supports data exports to MS Excel, MS Access and SQL.Hope this help, Let me know which plc you have and are you using any HMI with this?

Comment: I am using an Indraworks MTX 14v10 as the PLC. HMI will be used at a later stage but all I want to find out right now is how can I possibly setup a socket connection between the PLC and the MongoDB?

Comment: I'm not familiar with indraworks, i've to go through the documentation, i'll let you know if I find anything good

Comment: Thank you.

ftp://ftp.boschrexroth.pl/brc/XLC_MLC_12/il_2g_baslib__v12li_2011-05.pdf

Here's the link I found.

Comment: Could you help me with this? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35320715/trying-to-send-data-from-plc-to-pc-over-tcp-ip-sockets-but-unable-to-see-it-on-r

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure which PLC you are using but I'm using the Bosch XM22 and L75.  It has an opcua server which I can read values from.  I've used python and javascript so var, once I have I've been pushing it to mysql.

Comment: If your using an older L65 or something I'm curious as well how you did it if you've already solved this.